Convert polyline features to polygons given the attributes using ArcGIS Pro
Is there a geoprocessing tool or a technique in ArcGIS Pro to convert polylines (A) to polygons (B) taking into account the attributes?
The geoprocessing tool "Feature to Polygon" allows conversion of polyline features to polygons. However, attributes from polylines do not seem to be transferred to the polygons. E.g. the field "contourline" with the values 5, 10 and 20 in the feature file is not transferred to the polygon file.
A workaround is:

select all polylines with the same "contourline" value
convert the selected polylines to polygons
add field "contourline" to the polygons & enter corresponding value
merge the individual polygon files

The disadvantage of this workaround is that nested polygons do not cut holes. Enveloping polylines are converted to filled polygons like X in the figure. The subsequent cutting process can become quite time-consuming.


I'd think you'd be better off asking how to automate the final step, removing the overlaps. Automating figure/ground relationships is tricky, but you have several options here, including the use of a topology.

So your question is about making non-overlapping polygons and you mention contours. Do you have the original DEM that you created the polylines from? If so it would suggest you used the contour tool to create the polylines. If that's the case then you need only change the parameter contour type to CONTOUR POLYGON

This is reverse of what you are doing. Input:

Use feature to polygon:

Create a copy of output and remove holes inside each polygon using field calculator
on field Shape:
def outRing(shp):
 part=shp.getPart(0)
 pgon=arcpy.Polygon(part)
 return pgon
------
outRing( !Shape!)

Spatially join them to original lines using 'SHARE_A_LINE_SEGMENT_WITH'. Field join  NON_OVERLAPS with no holes polygons:

Not sure if this is a useful result, because range of elevation values remains unknown.
